# How to use UTF8 model with material like MeshPhongMaterial?

Tags: three.js

i really want to use utf8 format because it's very light, but the material in webgl_loader_utf8.html examples set like this:

```
 object.traverse( function( node ) {

                                      node.castShadow = true;
                                      node.receiveShadow = true;

                                      if ( node.material && node.material.name === "skin" ) {

                                            node.material.wrapAround = true;
                                            node.material.wrapRGB.set( 0.6, 0.2, 0.1 );

                                      }

                                    } 
                );
```

I haven't seen this before so i don't get it.

Can i use utf8loader with some normal material like MeshPhongMaterial?   And how to do that?

Or if that's not impossible so can anyone give me some information about that type of material?

Thank you very much. (Three.js r65)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try out shininess for material...

```
object.traverse( function( node ) {
node.castShadow = true;
node.receiveShadow = true;
if ( node.material && node.material.name === "skin" ) {
      node.material.wrapAround = true;
      node.material.wrapRGB.set( 0.6, 0.2, 0.1 );
      node.material.shininess = 100; // it should between 0-1000
   }
});
```